# Does WP show me if I'm logged in from multiple locations?

Tags: security, login, ip

Does word press show me if I'm logged in in another location?

Related: [Limiting sessions to one IP at a time](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/limiting-sessions-to-one-ip-at-a-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When WordPress logs you in, it creates a cookie on your system to keep you logged in if you want.  However, being logged in from another location doesn't have much meaning in this context.

When you go back to your WP site, WordPress will check for the existence of this authentication cookie on your system.  If it's there and valid, you'll be logged in.  If it's missing or invalid, you'll have to log in again.

However, WordPress doesn't track if you're logged in on one machine versus another at the same time.  You could probably set up a plug-in of some sort to track which users are logged in using sessions or [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) ... but this isn't WordPress' default behavior.

Comment: Come to think of it ... this would be an interesting addition from a security perspective.  A plug-in that only allows you to log in from one location at a time and automatically invalidates your authentication cookie when you log in from another location ... great idea *@Moshie*!

Comment: A plugin to more stringently control authentication in this manner would be a great addition to the plugin directory. :D